# Columns Layout export

Tags: enterprise-architect

Sparx Enterprise Architect offers the possibility to define custom layouts for list views in the package browser and to save these definitions. When exporting a Project file (*.eap) via xmi, these definitions are not included in the export-file and thus lost. I wonder whether there exists a way to transfer columns layout definitions between two EA-Projects.

Many thanks in advance for every hint!

Comment: Can you show where/how they are defined? I'd expected something in the Reference Data Export, but there's nothing on first view that targets in that direction.

Comment: other places to look is %appdata% and registry

Comment: @Thomas You enter the package browser e.g. by choosing 'View as List' when right-clicking on a package in the projekt browser. All elements contained in the selected package (and its sub-packages) are shown as list then. Right-clicking on the list view offers an entry 'Columns Layout' where You may store and reload Your custom layouts.

Comment: @geert In %appdata% there is e.g. a rubric 'Search Data' where custom searches are stored - but unfortunately nothing about columns layout. The registry is another good idea; but I don't have access to the registry because I use the EA on a restricted workplace. So, I cannot check this suggestion by myself. Nevertheless, many thanks.

Comment: I will have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Geert suggested the layout is stored in the registry.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems\EA400\EA\OPTIONS]
```

holds a key `PKG_BRWSE_LAYOUTS` with the comma separated list of profile names (so you better don't use comma in your profile name ;-).

The detailed information is stored in

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems\EA400\EA\EA1200Workspace\BCGPGrids\EA_ELEMENT_LIST_<name>BCGPGrid-0]
```

where `<name>` is the according profile name.

For a sample layout here they looked like

```
"Columns"=hex:11,00,01,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"ColumnWidth"=hex:11,00,16,00,00,00,04,01,00,00,50,00,00,00,50,00,00,00,50,00,\
  00,00,50,00,00,00,50,00,00,00,50,00,00,00,50,00,00,00,50,00,00,00,50,00,00,\
  00,50,00,00,00,50,00,00,00,50,00,00,00,50,00,00,00,50,00,00,00,50,00,00,00
"ColumnOrder"=hex:08,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,06,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,0d,00,\
  00,00,0e,00,00,00,0f,00,00,00,10,00,00,00
"Groupping"=hex:00,00
"LastFieldChooserPos"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"IsFieldChooserVisible"=dword:00000000
"IsFieldChooserThemed"=dword:00000001
"SortColumns"=hex:00,00
```

I have to leave that to you to decipher the coding used here. But for a pure ex-/import you probably don't need to do that.

Comment: Many thanks; this way it should be easy to find and use. I am going to close my question.